# Story problem - Linear algebra - solving linear systems in two variables with substitution

Tags: linear-algebra, word-problem

A rocket is fired from Spain at a constant rate of 5 meters per second toward France. After the rocket had traveled 10 meters, France launches a rocket right behind it to catch it at a rate of 6.5 meters per sec. When will the France rocket intercept the Spain rocket, and how far wil they have traveled at the time of interception?

y=5x   and  y=6.5x + -13.

5x=6.5x + -13

x=8.66 and y=43. (Answer)

I don't understand where the -13 comes from in setting up the problem. 
I understand the rest. Please help.

Comment: After two seconds the rocket from Spain has travelled 10 meters. After two seconds the rocket from France starts. Thus it hasn´t travelled 0 meters. Therefore the equation for the rocket from France is $0=6.5\cdot 2+b$

Answer (score 0):

You know speed of rocket launcged from spain its $5m/s$ it has travelled 10m  which implies time is $2$ seconds so the gap between time is $2$ seconds . We know $d=s.t$ so the distance gap will be $6.5*2=13$. Now lets answer your question if you know the concept of relative velocity then its clear. If both rockets travel in same direction then its $-13$ if in opposite direction then $+13$.